# How to specify data defined rounded background corners for labels in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

In QGIS 2 I could specify data defined rounded corners for labels background, using a string, for example '5, 5' :
[image: QGIS 2]

In QGIS 3, this same syntax is correctly recognised by the expression generator, but labels corners remain square :
[image: QGIS 3]

Does anyone know the right syntax or is this a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug - see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/6493. A fix will be in 3.0.1.